# ASP.NET Core Facebook Authentication Middleware user picture

Tags: facebook, authentication, asp.net-core, claims

I'm trying to retrieve user profile picture with Facebook Authentication middleware in ASP.NET Core 1.0. I have managed to add these configurations to make the user picture availble

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
            AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"],
            Scope = { "public_profile" },
            Fields = { "picture" }
        });
```

and to retrieve data

```
var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

and

```
var userName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName);
```

But How can I now retrieve user picture as there is not **Claim Type** for it?

Comment: how did you define `info` in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Set said in his answer you can get the picture using the Facebook [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)  like this `https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture`.

Example code :

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var identifier = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); 
var picture = $"https://graph.facebook.com/{identifier}/picture";
```

You might want to check if `info` is not null and if `info.LoginProvider` is facebook.

Comment: So NameIdentifier is the user Id?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, you can see the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookHandler.cs#L48).

Comment: The code provided by tmg does not return the Facebook User ID but rather the User ID used in the web application. How can I get the Facebook User ID?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in general, the standard (oauth) implementation of UserInfo Endpoint may return picture in response if you specify `Fields = { "picture" }`.

Facebook Graph API provides https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me as UserInformation endpoint and ASP.NET Core Facebook Auth Middleware uses it for claims population.

The problem is that Facebook Graph API doesn't return `picture` in response if you use this `\me` endpoint. They did so before but for some reason have removed that. Related SO: [facebook oauth, no picture with basic permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11748941/2833802)

But you can get the picture using:
https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/picture

Comment: So would I have to do it in javascript? Get the username/user_id then retrieve it?

Comment: and can you point me to some examples or documentations about this middleware?

Comment: @Ahmad you may do this call on client or server side - just use access token with request. I'm afraid the best info about middleware right now is the source on github only https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook

Comment: ty! can you plz include example of how would you do it on the server side.. maybe by somehow extending this middleware or something

Comment: as I'm new to ASP.NET Core I couldn't understand how to do it with other similar answers give for somewhat similar question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

In my project ASP.NET Core 2.2 I use this code:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
        options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = (context) =>
        {
            var picture = $"https://graph.facebook.com/{context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)}/picture?type=large";
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Picture", picture));
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

And in Controller, in ExternalLoginCallback action I retrieve value this way:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var picture = info.Principal.FindFirstValue("Picture");
```