# Kentico - Fetch profile photo of user when logging in

Tags: kentico

I have used a login form that has option to login from social media account like Facebook, LinkedIn etc. Now when the user selects the Facebook Login option i want to bring the profile photo of the user.

Can i fetch the profile photo from social media account ? Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is more question for [facebook graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748941/facebook-oauth-no-picture-with-basic-permissions)

Comment: Could you provide a version of Kentico you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are using v11/V12 of Kentico.

According to the [docs](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/facebook-authentication/loading-user-information-from-facebook-profiles)(v 11 docs) - profile picture mapping is not provided out of the box.

You could map the user profile link when the user logs in. Then make a scheduled task, event handler listening user create or update to load the profile picture.